# is there any irc chat room for directx 9 c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, irc, directx-9

is there any active irc chat room that have people to talk to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stackoverflow's new chat utility. Perhaps people can answer your questions there. You could also try irc.rohitab.com - some talented coders are often present there.

Comment: can you give me an  link for stackoverflow chat utility

Comment: C++ stackoverflow lounge: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/c-lounge